# Difference between using 'dynamic' vs base type when instantiating object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, factory

I am somewhat confused as to what the best approach would be when it comes to creating a new object when the type of this object is unknown until run time. Suppose I have a base class called Store in the following manner:

```
public class Store
{
   public Store()
   {
     Inventory = new List<Inventory>()
   }

   public string Title { get; set;} 
   public ICollection<Inventory> Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose that I have another class which inherits from the `Store` class. Let's call it, PetStore. In PetStore, I define a constructor, which is called whenever the `StoreFactory` creates an object:

PetStore

```
public PetStore(Store store) : base(store)
{
    Title = ((PetStore)store).Title;
}
```

Using `StoreFactory` and reflection to instantiate an object:

```
public static Store FromTemplate(Store store)
{       
    Type type = Type.GetType(store.StoreType.ClassName);
    Store newstore = Activator.CreateInstance(type, store) as Store;
    return newstore;
}
```

To get to the heart of the question now; what is the difference in instantiating an object by doing the following:

```
Store newStore = StoreFactory.FromTemplate(existingPetStore);
```

and

```
dynamic newStore = StoreFactory.FromTemplate(existingPetStore);
```

I am not sure if I'm wording the question properly. It might be a bit confusing, I apologize if that's the case.  But, I am looking to understand how MVC differentiates between these two and ultimately, which is the best approach to use in this case.

Comment: I believe there are some pretty significant differences. I wouldn't recommend using `dynamic` here. I'd have to review the docs to provide specific differences though I'm sure someone like Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet can provide you with a thorough answer.

Comment: I appreciate your input :)

Comment: Sorry it's not more useful. One argument against it is you don't have compile time type safety when you use it. Some would be compile time errors will instead manifest as run time errors. In addition to that I think it will require your code to work with the Dynamic Language Runtime in addition to the Common Language Runtime and perform many checks at run time which will negatively impact performance. Maybe I should be putting that as an answer?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "Dynamic Language Runtime", but if you mean loading additional references, I don't believe this is true. However, the part about run time errors and such I was aware of, I guess I wanted to know the benefits towards using dynamic vs the other approach

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx read up. It absolutely adds references, probably quite a lot.

Comment: `dynamic` and the DLR as you'll read in that article was largely added for interoperability and (at least Microsoft says :p) to enable language designers by offloading a lot of boiler plate work.

Comment: Thanks for all your input @evanmcdonnal :) Just wrap up everything in an answer format and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Alright, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One argument against it is you don't have compile time type safety when you use it. Some would be compile time errors will instead manifest as run time errors.

In addition to that I think it will require your code to work with the Dynamic Language Runtime in addition to the Common Language Runtime. Your code will also perform many checks at run time which will negatively impact performance.

To read more about the DLR check out this article on msdn; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx

Answer (score 2):

ASP MVC does not differentiate between the two, it's the C# compiler that will. From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx)

> The dynamic type enables the operations in which it occurs to bypass compile-time type checking. Instead, these operations are resolved at run time.
>
> ...
>
> Type dynamic behaves like type object in most circumstances. However, operations that contain expressions of type dynamic are not resolved or type checked by the compiler. The compiler packages together information about the operation, and that information is later used to evaluate the operation at run time. As part of the process, variables of type dynamic are compiled into variables of type object. Therefore, type dynamic exists only at compile time, not at run time.

Basically what this means is that you can do stuff like this:

```
dynamic store = new Store();
store = 1;
store = "string";
store = new List<Store>();
```

Although it would work in your store example, you increase the chance of errors by giving yourself a chance to accidentally assign values that are not of the same type. Then, when you go to use it, you'll get an exception. Not only can you run into issues easier, it's just not necessary.

Instantiating the type using the base class is the better option.

```
Store newStore = StoreFactory.FromTemplate(existingPetStore);
```

I'm confused, though, as to why you're using reflection in your factory. It seems like a waste to me... Why not return a `new PetStore` with all of the properties set you want set? Or, if `existingPetStore` is not known at runtime, why not have your object implement `ICloneable` and do a `MemberwiseClone` or something? Reflection seems to be an odd choice in my mind...

Comment: That is interesting, and a very thorough response! Maybe even a bit more simple than what I expected. Thank you! And in response to cloning vs factory...why would it be better to implement the interface as opposed to the factory? I am rather new at MVC (as you might be able to tell). The only reason why a factory seemed to make more sense is because I do not want a complete copy of the element, just some properties (as in this case, 'Title').